# Disable trailing slash redirect in Apache so POST requests work with index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, post, trailing-slash

I'm setting a index.php script that will take sent POST requests, but when sending such requests the trailing slash is added through a 301 redirect and the POST data is lost.

For instance:

1. POST request is made to host/test
2. Server redirects to host/test/
3. POST data is lost

Note that the request MUST be sent to host/test, not to host/test/.

To fix this, I either need to:

- Make so that the POST data is passed along to the redirected url (using the SESSION didn't work as the redirect happens before the script is read)
- Stop the automatic redirect that adds the trailing slash from happening (already tried messing with DirectorySlash Off on .htaccess, didn't work)
- Something else

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: OK. So what is your question?

Comment: I very much doubt that a redirection rule will add a backslash to some URL. A slash, sure, but not a backslash. Except of course if you explicitly coded that.

Comment: Thanks! I mean the slash at the end of the URL. It's added automatically by the server, i.e. when requesting "host/test" it redirects to "host/test/" and thus POST data is lost. AFAIK it's default behavior for apache

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/250161/how-do-i-remove-trailing-slashes-from-a-url-when-using-apaches-default-director